# How to detect if a website "woke up"

Tags: javascript, web-applications

I have a web-app which needs to be updated when it "woke up" from e.g. the laptop was closed and opened again. A test for lost and regained connectivity does not work in this case. What other options do I have?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? See the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Stale data ... and curiosity :-)